# SBC power on LED Indication

Tags: circuit-analysis, sbc

I am using SBC [ABP 3000](http://www.vecow.com/dispUploadBox/PJ-VECOW/Files/6265.pdf) in my application. The SBC will be placed inside a unit. I need to provide the SBC turn on and Off status to the external LED for indication.

In the [user manual](http://www.vecow.com/dispUploadBox/PJ-VECOW/Files/6430.pdf), the J-status pin provides a voltage that is driving the SBC's LED. The LED present on the SBC is Bicolour LED.

How I can use this j-status pins to drive a 12V LED?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq2mvL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using an opto-isolator gives isolation and the ability to switch the 12 V LED on the anode side or on the cathode side with no worries about which way the SBC has its switching and current limiting resistor arranged.*